# Correct way to use " " while creating sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

**I am confused about why at some places it is necessary to place " "  at some distance from the text.
For E.g. In "CREATE TABLE ", the " is placed at some distance from TABLE.**

```
String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION = "CREATE TABLE "+ UtilConstants.TABLE_NAME+"(" + UtilConstants.KEY_ID
        + " Integer PRIMARY KEY," + UtilConstants.KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
        UtilConstants.KEY_PHONENUMBER + "TEXT" +  ")";
db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically by writing this code

```
String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION = "CREATE TABLE "+ UtilConstants.TABLE_NAME+"(" + UtilConstants.KEY_ID
        + " Integer PRIMARY KEY," + UtilConstants.KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
        UtilConstants.KEY_PHONENUMBER + "TEXT" +  ")";
db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION);
```

you are just going to create a SQL query.

Now imagine if you don't put a space after table the query will be something like this

```
CREATE TABLEsomeTableName ......
```

where  **someTableName** is table name  then it will cause an error because it is not a SQL query at all

> Note : you don't have to mention space after table If
>   **UtilConstants.KEY_NAME** contains space at the beginning that also works ...

Answer (score 0):

The SQL command would be `CREATE TABLE [name]`
You need the distance to produce the space, if you would not use the distance the command would be `CREATE TABLE[name]` it would detect it as two words
For example, you have in `String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION` a space between `String` and `DATABASE_TABLE_CREATION` it would not work if you remove the space

Answer (score 0):

Its because if you don't have the space " " character after these keyword like `TABLE`, the sql command will understand your keyword like `TABLE[your_table_name]` and that is not a valid SQL term.